# Printf example in bash does not create a newline

Tags: bash, printf

Working with `printf` in a bash script, adding no spaces after `"\n"` does not create a newline, whereas adding a space creates a newline, e. g.:

1. No space after `"\n"`

   ```
   NewLine=`printf "\n"`
   echo -e "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   FirstlineLastline
   ```
2. Space after `"\n "`

   ```
   NewLine=`printf "\n "`
   echo -e "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   Firstline
    Lastline
   ```

Question: Why doesn't 1. create the following result:

```
Firstline 
Lastline
```

I know that this specific issue could have been worked around using other techniques, but I want to focus on why 1. does not work.

Edited:
When using echo instead of printf, I get the expected result, but why does printf work differently?

```
    NewLine=`echo "\n"`
    echo -e "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"
```

Result:

```
    Firstline
    Lastline
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The backtick operator removes trailing new lines. See **3.4.5. Command substitution** at http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html

### Note on edited question

Compare:

```
[alvaro@localhost ~]$ printf "\n"

[alvaro@localhost ~]$ echo "\n"
\n
[alvaro@localhost ~]$ echo -e "\n"


[alvaro@localhost ~]$
```

The echo command doesn't treat `\n` as a newline unless you tell him to do so:

```
NAME
       echo - display a line of text
[...]
       -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
```

POSIX 7 specifies this behaviour [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03):

> [...] with the standard output of the command, removing sequences of one or more  characters at the end of the substitution

Comment: The thing is that this does not seem to be the case 
for the example in the edited part of the post, i.e the part:   NewLine=`echo "\n"`

Comment: So I guess the **conclusion** is that:
**1)** Printf works differently than echo in this case, in that echo requires "-e" for creating the actual newline
**2)** All trailing newlines gets deleted, both in printf and in echo -e, as described in: 
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html 
The post by mr. Dennis Williamson below was also useful to point out these issues. Thx!

Comment: Is there a POSIX 7 workaround to avoid that behavior (I want to keep newlines), except writing to temp files or pipes?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe people will come here with the same problem I had:
echoing \n inside a code wrapped in backsticks. A little tip:

```
printf "astring\n"
# and 
printf "%s\n" "astring" 
# both have the same effect.
# So... I prefer the less typing one
```

The short answer is:

```
# Escape \n correctly !

# Using just: printf "$myvar\n" causes this effect inside the backsticks:
printf "banana
"

# So... you must try \\n  that will give you the desired 
printf "banana\n"

# Or even \\\\n if this string is being sent to another place 
# before echoing,

buffer="${buffer}\\\\n printf \"$othervar\\\\n\""
```

One common problem is that if you do inside the code:

```
echo 'Tomato is nice'
```

when surrounded with backsticks will produce the error

```
command Tomato not found.
```

The workaround is to add another echo -e or printf

```
printed=0

function mecho(){
  #First time you need an "echo" in order bash relaxes.
  if [[ $printed == 0 ]]; then
    printf "echo -e $1\\\\n"
    printed=1
  else
    echo -e "\r\n\r$1\\\\n"
  fi
}
```

Now you can debug your code doing in prompt just:

```
(prompt)$  `mySuperFunction "arg1" "etc"`
```

The output will be nicely

```
 mydebug: a value
 otherdebug: whathever appended using myecho
 a third string
```

and debuging internally with

```
mecho "a string to be hacktyped"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$ printf -v NewLine "\n"
$ echo -e "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"

Firstline
Lastline

$ echo "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"
Firstline
Lastline
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like BASH is removing trailing newlines.
e.g.

```
NewLine=`printf " \n\n\n"`
echo -e "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"
Firstline Lastline

NewLine=`printf " \n\n\n "`
echo -e "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"
Firstline


 Lastline
```

Answer (score 4):

Your edited `echo` version is putting a literal backslash-n into the variable `$NewLine` which then gets interpreted by your `echo -e`. If you did this instead:

```
NewLine=$(echo -e "\n")
echo -e "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"
```

your result would be the same as in case #1. To make *that* one work that way, you'd have to escape the backslash and put the whole thing in single quotes:

```
NewLine=$(printf '\\n')
echo -e "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"
```

or double escape it:

```
NewLine=$(printf "\\\n")
```

Of course, you could just use `printf` directly or you can set your NewLine value like this:

```
printf "Firstline\nLastline\n"
```

or

```
NewLine=$'\n'
echo "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"    # no need for -e
```

Comment: this is confusing and -- if one where to nitpick -- also wrong. for example: in the second code block you say you escape the newline but you really only escape the backslash (the "escape").

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'll try to clarify it.

Comment: Thx. for this answer as well. Was not able to upvote it because "it was to old to be changed", according to the system.

Answer (score 4):

For people coming here wondering how to use newlines in arguments to `printf`, use `%b` instead of `%s`:

```sh
$> printf "a%sa" "\n"
a\na
$> printf "a%ba" "\n"
a
a
```

From the manual:

> %b    expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument

Comment: This was the solution for me and it works __at least__ since 2011 (Bash 4.2.46). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We do not need "echo" or "printf" for creating the NewLine variable:

```
NewLine="
"
printf "%q\n" "${NewLine}"
echo "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Bash delete all trailing newlines in commands substitution.

To save trailing newlines, assign `printf` output to the variable with `printf -v VAR`

instead of

```
NewLine=`printf "\n"`
echo -e "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"
#FirstlineLastline
```

use

```
printf -v NewLine '\n'
echo -e "Firstline${NewLine}Lastline"
#Firstline
#Lastline
```

#### Explanation

According to bash man

> ##### 3.5.4 Command Substitution
>
> **$(command)**
>
> or
>
> **`command`**
>
> **Bash** performs the expansion by executing *command* and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted**. Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word splitting.

So, after adding any trailing newlines, bash will delete them.

```
var=$(printf '%s\n%s\n\n\n' 'foo' 'bar')
echo "$var"
```

output:

```
foo
bar
```

According to `help printf`

> `printf [-v var] format [arguments]`
>
> If the -v option is supplied, the output is placed into the value of the shell variable VAR rather than being sent to the standard output.

In this case, for safe copying of formatted text to the variable, use the `[-v var]` option:

```
printf -v var '%s\n%s\n\n\n' 'foo' 'bar'
echo "$var"
```

output:

```
foo
bar
```

Answer (score -3):

Works ok if you add "\r"

```
$ nl=`printf "\n\r"` && echo "1${nl}2"
1
2
```

Comment: The Windows line feed is \r\n, it you were referring to that :-?